# Calls to Addresses in the Middle of Routines

Tags: debugging, gdb, function-call, backtrace, intel-pin

I am tracing `wireshark-2.6.10` using `Pin`. At several points during the initialization, I can see some calls, such as this:

```
00000000004e9400 <__libc_csu_init@@Base>:
  ...
  4e9449:       41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
  ...
```

The target of this call is `0x197db0`, shown here:

```
0000000000197cb0 <_start@@Base>:
  ...
  197db0:       55                      push   %rbp
  197db1:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  197db4:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  197db5:       e9 66 ff ff ff          jmpq   197d20 <_start@@Base+0x70>
  197dba:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  ...
```

`Pin` says that this is in the middle of the containing routine, i.e., `_start@@Base`. But, when I reach this target using `gdb`, I see the following output:

```
>│0x5555556ebdb0 <frame_dummy>                                    push   %rbp
 │0x5555556ebdb1 <frame_dummy+1>                                  mov    %rsp,%rbp
 │0x5555556ebdb4 <frame_dummy+4>                                  pop    %rbp
 │0x5555556ebdb5 <frame_dummy+5>                                  jmpq   0x5555556ebd20 <register_tm_clones>
 │0x5555556ebdba <frame_dummy+10>                                 nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 │0x5555556ebdc0 <main_window_update()>                           xor    %edi,%edi
```

Note that if I subtract the bias value, the runtime target address will be consistent with the compile time value (i.e., `0x5555556ebdb0 - 0x555555554000 = 0x197db0`). It seems that there exists a `pseudo-routine` called `frame_dummy` inside `_start@@Base`. How is that possible? How can I extract the addresses for these `pseudo-routines`, beforehand (i.e., before execution)?

**UPDATE:**

These types of calls to the middle of functions were not present in `GIMP` and `Anjuta` (which are written almost purely in `C` and built from source). But are present in `Inkscape` and `Wireshark` (written in `C++`, although I do not think that the language is the cause. These two were installed from packages.).

At first, it seemed that this situation occurs only during the initialization and before calling the `main()` function. But, at least in `wireshark-2.6.10` this occurs at least in one place after `main()` starts. Here, we have `wireshark-qt.cpp: Lines 522-524` (which is part of `main()`).

```
/* Get the compile-time version information string */
comp_info_str = get_compiled_version_info(get_wireshark_qt_compiled_info,
                      get_gui_compiled_info);
```

This is a call to `get_compiled_version_info()`. In assembly, the function is called at address `0x5555556e74c2 (0x1934c2 without bias)`, as shown below:

```
>│0x5555556e74c2 <main(int, char**)+178>  callq  0x5555556f5870 <get_compiled_version_info>
 │0x5555556e74c7 <main(int, char**)+183>  lea    0x4972(%rip),%rdi        # 0x5555556ebe40 <get_wireshark_runtime_info(_GString*)>
 │0x5555556e74ce <main(int, char**)+190>  mov    %rax,%r13
```

Again, the target is in the middle of another function, `_ZN7QStringD1Ev@@Base`:

```
00000000001980f0 <_ZN7QStringD1Ev@@Base>:
...
1a1870:       41 54                   push   %r12
...
```

This is the output of `gdb`  (`0x5555556f5870 - 0x555555554000 = 0x1a1870`):

```
>│0x5555556f5870 <get_compiled_version_info>      push   %r12
 │0x5555556f5872 <get_compiled_version_info+2>    mov    %rdi,%r12
 │0x5555556f5875 <get_compiled_version_info+5>    push   %rbp
 │0x5555556f5876 <get_compiled_version_info+6>    lea    0x349445(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555a3ecc2
```

As can be seen, the debugger recognizes that this address is the start address of `get_compiled_version_info()`. This is because it has access to `debug_info`. In all cases that I found, the symbol for these `pseudo-routines` were removed from the original binary (because `.symtab` was removed from the binary). But the strange thing is that it is located inside `_ZN7QStringD1Ev@@Base`. Therefore, `Pin` considers `get_compiled_version_info()` to be inside `_ZN7QStringD1Ev@@Base`.

Answer (score 1):

> How is that possible?

The [frame_dummy](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/crtstuff.c#L461) is a bona-fide C function. If `Pin` thinks it's in the middle of `_start`, it's probably because:

1. `_start` is an assembly function, and
2. its `.st_size` is set incorrectly in the symbol table.

You can confirm this by looking at `readelf -Ws a.out | egrep ' (_start|frame_dummy)'`.

You are probably using the binary linked with fairly old GLIBC.

GLIBC used to generate C runtime startup files (whence `_start` comes from) by using `gcc -S` to create assembly from C source, then splitting and editing the assembly with `sed`. Getting `.size` directive wrong was one problem with that approach, and it is no longer used on `x86_64` as of 2012 ([commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ed656b4065ae8b948e67a865c0964f24e90c5133)).

> How can I extract the addresses for these pseudo-routines, beforehand (i.e., before execution)?

Pin doesn't magically create these pseudo-routines, they must be visible in the `readelf -Ws` output of the original binary.

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian. Your hints are as always invaluable. My main problem is that `Pin` does not detect these pseudo-routines (`frame_dummy`,...). `readelf` also does not detect the symbol. I installed the `dbgsym` package and saw that the symbol was there. In any case, having the definition of a routine inside another routine looks particularly strange. Precisely, I need to generate the backtrace in `Pin` and I determine `calls` by comparing the start of `BB` with the start of routines, so this rare case is problematic. But if this happens only before `main()`, I can safely ignore it.

Comment: Well, I handled the problem using the addresses in the debug info.